# Why script in custom_filters_score behaves as boost?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "name": "user1234"
        }
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "subject": "math"
            }
          },
          "script": "_score + doc['subject_score'].value"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If script is having like above it gives `Error: unresolvable property or identifier: _score`
If script is like `"script": "doc['subject_score'].value"` It multiplies the _score in similar way boost does. I want to replace the elasticsearch _score with custom score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you would like to use elasticsearch scoring if subject is not math and you would like to use custom scoring with subject is math. If you are using Elasticsearch v0.90.4 or higher, it can be achieved using new `function_score` query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "name": "user1234"
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "subject": "math"
                    }
                },
                "script_score": {
                    "script": "doc[\"subject_score\"].value"
                }
            }, {
                "boost_factor": 0

            }],
            "score_mode": "first",
            "boost_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to v0.90.4 you would have to resort to using combination of `custom_score` and `custom_filters_score`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "custom_score": {
            "query": {
                "custom_filters_score": {
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "name": "user1234"
                        }
                    },
                    "filters": [{
                        "filter": {
                            "term": {
                                "subject": "math"
                            }
                        },
                        "script": "-1.0"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "script": "_score < 0.0 ? _score * -1.0 + doc[\"subject_score\"].value : _score"
        }
    }
}
```

or as @javanna suggested, use multiple custom_score queries combined together by bool query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "disable_coord": true,
            "should": [{
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "name": "user1234"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "subject": "math"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "custom_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "term": {
                                    "name": "user1234"
                                }
                            },
                            "script": "doc['subject_score'].value"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "subject": "math"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, this means that there's no way to use _score in a script field inside a custom_score_filters block. You can only modify _score in other scripts associated with other queries. Is that right?

Comment: Indeed prior to v0.90.4 _score was inaccessible in the custom_filters_score script. After v0.90.4 the situation has changed. See https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-test-scripts/blob/master/function_score.sh for different examples of solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I'd like to say that there are many ways of customising the scoring in elasticsearch and it seems like you may have accidentally picked the wrong one. I will just summarize two and you will see what the problem is:

### Custom Filters Score

If you [read the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query/) (carefully) on `custom_filters_score` then you will see that it there for performance reasons, to be able to use for scoring the the faster filter machinery of elasticsearch. (Filters are faster as scoring is not calculated when computing the hit set, and they are cached between requests.)

At the end of the docs; it mentions `custom_filters_score` can take a `"script"` parameter to use instead of a `"boost"` parameter per `filter`. Best way to think of this is to calculate a number, which will be passed up to the parent query to be combined with the other sibling queries to calculate the total score for the document.

### Custom Score Query

[Reading the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/) this is used when you want to customise the score from the query and change it how you wish. There is a `_score` variable available to you to use in your `"script"` which is the score of the query inside the `custom_score` query.

Try this:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "custom_score": {
                "query": { 
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "script": "doc['subject_score'].value" //*see note below
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "subject": "math"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "name": "user1234"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: If you wanted to you could use `_score` here. Also, I moved both your `"term"` parts to filters as any match of a term would get the same score and filters are faster.

Good luck!